# Is it required to encode input in scikit-learn where trained data is encoded?

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoding

I'm new to python.
I have trained my *algorithm* strong text on **categorical** data, and during training I faced some errors for the solution. I saw that it requires using a `LabelEncoder` and I used that. Hence, the problem was solved and the algorithm training was completed.

I would like to know why is it not accepting the **string that was the original data** (before encoding).
*Is there any way to to give string characters to an algorithm for prediction?*
Here is my code:

---

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

df=pd.read_csv(r'E:\Study\FYP Data\FYP\datasets\alluni.csv', encoding= 'unicode_escape')
df.head()


Obtained Marks   Intermediate   Bachelor    Institute   %age
0   1001.0  FSc. Pre Medical    DPT          UOS      91.000000
1   1001.0  FSc. Pre Medical    DPT          UOS      91.000000
2   1010.0  FSc. Pre Medical    DPT          UOS      91.818182
3   1000.0  FSc. Pre Medical    DPT          UOS      90.909091
4   1000.0  FSc. Pre Medical    DPT          UOS      90.909091

le = LabelEncoder()
df['Intermediate'] = le.fit_transform(df.Intermediate.values)
df['Intermediate'] = le.fit_transform(df['Intermediate'])

le = LabelEncoder()
df['Institute'] = le.fit_transform(df.Institute.values)
df['Institute'] = le.fit_transform(df['Institute'])
df.head()

Obtained  Marks Intermediate    Bachelor    Institute
0   1001.0          16             DPT        7
1   1001.0          16             DPT        7
2   1010.0          16             DPT        7
3   1000.0          16             DPT        7
4   1000.0          16             DPT        7

df.drop(['%age'],axis=1,inplace=True)
X=df.drop('Bachelor',axis=1)
y=df['Bachelor']
X_train,X_text,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)

model2=DecisionTreeClassifier()
model2.fit(X_train,y_train)

model2.predict([['980','1','UOS']])
```

When i used this code, it showed me error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'UOS'`.
Is there any mechanism to give a `string` as input?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're using `LabelEncoder` to encode your training data, but you're still sending the original data when running the `model2.predict()`

Try encoding your data with LabelEncoder before running predict

```
data_encoded = le.transform([['980','1','UOS']])
model2.predict(data_encoded)
```

Comment: Thanks @Kasem Alsharaa dear but still shows me error 
*ValueError: bad input shape (1, 3)*